# PHP DateTime::createFromFormat doesn't parse ISO 8601 date time

Tags: php, datetime

Code speaks a million words:

```
php > echo strtotime("2010-12-07T23:00:00.000Z");
1291762800
echo date('c', 1291762800);
2010-12-08T00:00:00+01:00
php > var_dump(DateTime::createFromFormat('c', "2010-12-07T23:00:00.000Z"));
bool(false)
php > var_dump(DateTime::createFromFormat(DateTime::ISO8601, "2010-12-07T23:00:00.000Z"));
bool(false)
```

Any idea what's going on?

Btw, yes, new DateTime("2010-12-07T23:00:00.000Z") works fine. But I prefer to know what input I am getting.

Comment: Your fractional seconds aren't part of the format. `DateTime::ISO8601` is a string with the value `Y-m-d\TH:i:sO`.

Comment: WikiPedia disagrees:

Decimal fractions may also be added to any of the three time elements. A decimal point, either a comma or a dot (without any preference as stated most recently in resolution 10 of the 22nd General Conference CGPM in 2003), is used as a separator between the time element and its fraction. A fraction may only be added to the lowest order time element in the representation.

Comment: `public static DateTime DateTime::createFromFormat ( string $format , string $time [, DateTimeZone $timezone ] )`, maybe is caused by inclusive of the timezone

Comment: Seems like "c" and DateTime::ISO8601 aren't the same either:


    php > var_dump(DateTime::createFromFormat('c', "2010-12-10T19:02:09+01:00"));
bool(false)
php > var_dump(DateTime::createFromFormat('c', '2010-12-10T19:02:09+01:00'));
bool(false)
php > var_dump(DateTime::createFromFormat(DateTime::ISO8601, '2010-12-10T19:02:09+01:00'));
object(DateTime)#26 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(19) "2010-12-10 19:02:09"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(1)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(6) "+01:00"
}

Answer (score 48):

There's a bug report that exactly describes your problem :)

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51950

Since 2016-08-07, the bug report has been marked as "not a bug". You need to use `strtotime` or `new DateTime` instead.

The constants that have been defined apply to both formatting and parsing in the same way, which forces your ways.

Comment: Indeed disappointing. Why name a constant "ISO8601" if it's not actually compliant to that standard. This is why I don't like PHP much.

Comment: Bloody 7 years later and this still exists.... and is even marked as not a bug? `If you want to accept different ISO-8601 date/time formats`. Different ISO-8601 formats?? Why I dislike php in a nutshell.

Comment: Feeling the pain too

Comment: TBF, within PHP's design constraints, this is indeed not a bug. `createFromFormat` does not support *optional* date parts. That would be stupid to implement as well IMO, because the format specifiers use a simple syntax and a naive parser. PHP would have to support something like this: `Y-m-d\TH:i:s[?v]P` where the square brackets mean optional. That then probably has to be translated internally to regex. I'll have the naive parser, thanks. If you really want microseconds and you know that's the format you'll receive, use `Y-m-d\TH:i:s?vP`. If you want multiple formats just use `new DateTime`

Answer (score 18):

Parsing ISO8601 date, and also switching timezone:

```
// create ISO8601 dateTime 
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat(DateTime::ISO8601, '2016-07-27T19:30:00Z');

// set to user's timezone
$date -> setTimeZone('Asia/Singapore');

echo $date -> format(DateTime::ISO8601);
// prints '2016-07-28T03:30:00+0800'
```

Comment: copied your code and it prints: "2016-07-27T19:30:00+0000" using PHP 5.6.10

Comment: @AlexAngelico What is the output for `echo DateTime::ISO8601;`? It prints `Y-m-d\TH:i:sO` for me.

Comment: yes, DateTime::ISO8601 prints Y-m-d\TH:i:sO
I'm using this code to change the time to the correct Timezone. I'm in GMT-5
`$fecha_str = '2017-04-12T21:43:54+02:00';
 $date = strtotime($fecha_str);
 echo date("Y-m-d h:i:s", $date);
 /output=> 2017-04-12 07:43:54 `

Comment: Just as a heads up, don't use `format(\DateTime::ISO8601)` because it is not a valid ISO8601 format. Instead use either `c`, `\DateTime::ATOM` or `DATE_ATOM`. The reason is because the `\DateTime:ISO8601` way would wrongly stores as `2005-08-15T15:52:01+0000` when in actuality a valid ISO8601 date string should have a colon between the time zone designator like `2005-08-15T15:52:01+00:00`. This is mentioned in the PHP docs but is not immediately clear. Read the docs here: http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php#datetime.constants.iso860

Comment: Neither \DateTime::ISO8601 nor \DateTime::ATOM work for me for dates like '2020-02-04T00:00:00.000Z'. The 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s+' format works great.

Answer (score 16):

Nobody mentioned to use DATE_ATOM which is as far as i know phps most correct implementation of ISO 8601. It should at least work for the last 3 of these:

```
<?php

$dates = array(
    "2010-12-07T23:00:00.000Z",
    "2010-12-07T23:00:00",
    "2010-12-07T23:00:00Z",
    "2010-12-07T23:00:00+01:00",
    (new \DateTime("now"))->format(DATE_ATOM)
);

foreach($dates as $d) {

    $res = \DateTime::createFromFormat(DATE_ATOM, $d);

    echo "try $d: \n";
    var_dump($res);
    echo "\n\n";
}

?>
```

To be able to parse all of them i wrote a tiny function:

```
<?php

function parse_iso_8601($iso_8601_string) {
    $results = array();
    $results[] = \DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d\TH:i:s",$iso_8601_string);
    $results[] = \DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u",$iso_8601_string);
    $results[] = \DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uP",$iso_8601_string);
    $results[] = \DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d\TH:i:sP",$iso_8601_string);
    $results[] = \DateTime::createFromFormat(DATE_ATOM,$iso_8601_string);

    $success = array_values(array_filter($results));
    if(count($success) > 0) {
        return $success[0];
    }
    return false;
}

// Test
$dates = array(
    "2010-12-07T23:00:00.000Z",
    "2010-12-07T23:00:00",
    "2010-12-07T23:00:00Z",
    "2010-12-07T23:00:00+01:00",
    (new \DateTime("now"))->format(DATE_ATOM)
);

foreach($dates as $d) {

    $res = parse_iso_8601($d);

    echo "try $d: \n";
    var_dump($res);
    echo "\n\n";
}

?>
```

As @Glutexo mentioned it works only if there are only 1 to 6 precision digits for the decimal part, too. Feel free to improve it.

Comment: You’re the man! I was googling something like "*php parse all rfc 8601 formats*" and accidentally found your solution. It very helped me.

Comment: Why? This is basically what `new DateTime` does under the hood...

Answer (score 6):

try this:

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:sP', $date)
```

Comment: This value equals `DateTimeInterface::ATOM` or `DATE_ATOM`. Use a constant instead of a magic value.

Answer (score 6):

Simply :

```
$dt = new DateTime('2018-04-07T16:32:44Z');
$dt->format('Ymd'); // 20180407
```

Answer (score 5):

It is very strange and disappointing that this bug is still actual.
Here is a right pattern for parsing date with microseconds in decimal part of seconds:

```
Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uO
```

Usage:

```
$dateStr = '2015-04-29T11:42:56.000+0400'
$ISO = 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uO'
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat($ISO, $dateStr)
```

Comment: Actually, this work only if the decimal part of the seconds is present. Moreover, it works only if there are only 1 to 6 precision digits. If the decimal part is omitted or if it is more precise, false is returned.

Comment: Its work for me thx!

Answer (score 5):

Use `DATE_ATOM` rather than `'c'` when formatting like @Steven said. This is how you work with ISO 8601 in PHP.

```
<?php
$now_date = new DateTime();
$now_iso_8601 = $now_date->format(DATE_ATOM);
echo "Now in ISO 8601 format: {$now_iso_8601}\n";
$date_from_string_and_format = date_create_from_format(DATE_ATOM, $now_iso_8601);
echo "ISO 8601 formatted string, back to DateTime object:\n";
var_dump($date_from_string_and_format);
```

prints

```
Now in ISO 8601 format: 2018-09-05T08:17:35-10:00
ISO 8601 formatted string, back to DateTime object:
object(DateTime)#2 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2018-09-05 08:17:35.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(1)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(6) "-10:00"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For the answer listed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/14849503/2425651
we can use this format "Y-m-d\TH: i: s.u+" to keep the microseconds.

```
$format = 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u+';
$value = '2017-09-21T10:11:19.026Z'; // jsDate.toUTCString();
var_dump(\DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $value));
```

Answer (score 2):

This one works for me:

```
$date = (new DateTime)->setTimestamp(strtotime('2017-12-31T23:00:00.000Z'));
```

Comment: This is the only answer that interpretes the Z as UTC time and corrects it to the timezone php is in.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
$timeStamp = "2020-12-10T14:54:25.618Z";
var_dump(DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.v\Z', $timeStamp));
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2020-12-10 14:54:25.618000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(3) "UTC"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced this issue with POSTGRES default Time with timezone format and this was the format that fixed it for me:

`Y-m-d H:i:s.uO`

Answer (score 0):

I am using follow function that allow multiple ISO8601 formats:

```
function fromISO8601($time, \DateTimeZone $timezone = null) {
    // valid ISO time 2019-04-01T00:00:00.000+02:00
    $t = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uO', $time) or
    // ISO time without millis 2019-04-01T00:00:00+02:00
    $t = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:sO', $time) or
    // ISO time without timezone 2019-04-01T00:00:00.000
    $t = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u', $time, $timezone) or
    // ISO time without millis and timezone 2019-04-01T00:00:00.000+02:00
    $t = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', $time, $timezone);

    return $t;
}
```

here are all supported dates

```
var_dump(
    fromISO8601('2019-04-01T00:00:00.000+02:00'),
    fromISO8601('2019-04-01T00:00:00+02:00'),
    fromISO8601('2019-04-01T00:00:00.000'),
    fromISO8601('2019-04-01T00:00:00')
);
```

This code is benevolent for missing timezone and milliseconds and works in older php versions.