# PHP Parse date in ISO format

Tags: php, datetime

I'm currently using ConstantContact which returns XML with updated field in format like this:

```
2013-02-13T08:35:34.195Z
```

I'm assuming this is **date('c')** format.  How to parse this format? **strtotime** isn't returning correct value.

Comment: `date('c', strtotime($date));` ? Otherwise, what have you tried.

Comment: @AmazingDreams I don't really know what to try... I want to get unix timestamp from string representation.

Answer (score 32):

You may want to take a look at the [DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) function.

```
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s+', '2013-02-13T08:35:34.195Z');
```

The problem with that is you're going to loose the milliseconds.

The `+` sign in the format string simply tells this function to ignore the rest of the string instead of creating an error.

Confirmed in PHP7.2. As in comment below you can use `Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u\Z` to match the exact Js string that toISOString gives.

Comment: I don't really care about milliseconds, this seems to be working. Thanks

Comment: Using `'DateTime::ISO8601'` or `'c'` instead of `'Y-m-d\TH:i:s+'` in `createFromFormat()` also works...

Comment: I had to add the Timezone to make it work:
`DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s+', $isotime,  new DateTimeZone('Etc/Zulu'));`

Comment: @grim `'c'` does not work.

Comment: @Glutexo, I thought it did because because it is documented in: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php; but you're right, `'c'` doesn't work. For `DateTime::createFromFormat` one should obviously look at: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: Actually now. c does not match Js "ISO8601" nor does above mentioned. I recommend using `Y-m-d\TH:i:s.v\Z`

Comment: Appendix to my prior comment. Rather use `Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u\Z` it works both ways.

Comment: PHP now recommends using `\DateTime::ATOM` -> Note: This format is not compatible with ISO-8601, but is left this way for backward compatibility reasons. Use DateTime::ATOM or DATE_ATOM for compatibility with ISO-8601 instead.