# Jersey Restful service return date value format is changed

Tags: rest, jersey, swagger

I was developing an API using `Jersey` `Restful` service, every thing was working fine. the returned date value was in `milliseconds` on client side I had a logic to convert this date before rendering its value

```
$dateValue = ($dateValue * 0.001);
```

After completing the API part I wanted to add `Swagger` documentation, (I am not sure if this the reason). After all the documentation I have noticed that my dates are not displayed properly. 
Received date value from Jersey API is as follow. (format changed).

```
[insertDate] => 2015-07-13T08:08:58.000+0000
```

here is how it is declared in DTO class

```
private Date insertDate;
```

Comment: If it's JSON, it is a good change Swagger is culprit as it configures it's own Jackson provider, and that is the same provider used for your Jersey app. I am not sure how to change this behavior. I mean it's standard [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. If you can't find a solution to get the milliseconds back, I'm sure there are a number a libraries in whatever client you are using, to parse the date.

Comment: Yes its a JSON, If you add an answer with "this" description and explain the value `2015-07-13T08:08:58.000+0000` what it is e.g year-month-day, What is T here and then hour, minute and seconds and the `dot`, and `000+0000`, I will accept your answer. thanks

Comment: I don't know what language that is, it looks like PHP. You might find [this or the duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14849446/php-parse-date-in-iso-format) useful. Seems the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) API can handle your use case. I have no experience in PHP, so I couldn't help any further. As far as the `T`, from the link, it appears to be a simple delimiter and has no real "value". The zeros are milliseconds + UTC timezone offset

Comment: yes that is PHP. Main part of question is why it was happening you have answered that, format part is mostly answered, except the last info`000+0000`, however if you add this as an answer. I will accept that. Stackoverflow's way of saying thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swagger seems to be culprit. It configures it's own Jackson provider, and that is the same provider used for your Jersey app. I am not sure how to change this behavior. There was a [question raised](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28431468/2587435) where the OP was trying to configure the Jackson output, but I don't know if there was ever a solution. Maybe some digging around will give a more definite answer.

As far as the output, it's standard [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, so you should be able to find a library or standard PHP API to handle the parsing. I don't work with PHP, but looking at [this post or the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14849446/2587435), there is a [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) that can handle the parsing.

As far as your questions in the comments about the format, looking at the wikipedia link, it appears the `T` is no more than a delimiter (with no "value"). It could be replaced with a space, if the parsing library permitted it. The `000+0000` is the millisecond + the UTC timezone offset