# Modify microseconds of a PHP DateTime object

Tags: php, datetime

I have a PHP DateTime object with microseconds created as follows:

```
$time = microtime(true);
$microseconds = sprintf('%06d', ($time - floor($time)) * 1000000);

$dt = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s.' . $microseconds, $time));
```

How can I modify the microseconds value of `$dt`, without creating a completely new DateTime instance?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't.

There are three methods that can modify the value of a `DateTime` instance: `add`, `sub` and `modify`. We can rule out `add` and `sub` immediately because they work in terms of a `DateInterval` which does not have sub-second precision.

[`modify`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) accepts a string in one of the [standard recognized formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php). Of those formats, only the [relative](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) ones are of interest here because the other ones work in an absolute manner; and there is no relative format that allows tweaking the msec part (that unit is not recognized).

Comment: +1 here with a sad face, it's the correct answer but not the correct behaviour I expect from PHP.

Comment: So does the `Datetime` need to be converted to a string, manipulated there, then converted back to a `Datetime` again?

Comment: @Jason yes, there is no other way AFAIK.

Comment: That is quite some oversight. Been trying to truncate `Carbon` (an extension of `Datetime`) timestamps from a Xero API to whole seconds, and ended up using the intermediate string method. Raised it with `Carbon` [with my workaround here](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/issues/640#issuecomment-204198935). `Carbon` isn't an immutable class, so this approach does not sit well with it.

Comment: This is [no longer true](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53398348/1000608). However the manual doesn't reflect the newstuff™ yet.

Answer (score 10):

as of PHP 7.1
DateTime::setTime() supports microseconds.

Comment: Could work, but a nuisance if you don't need to change the hours, minutes or seconds for some reason. There's a [better solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53398348/1000608).

Comment: DateInterval as well adds f/F.

Answer (score 10):

This seems to have been available [since 7.1.0-rc4](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64887)

```
$dt = new DateTime('2020-01-01 0:00');
$dt->modify('+500 ms'); // Milliseconds.
$dt->modify('+123456 usec'); // Microseconds.
$dt->modify('+123456 microseconds'); // This works too.
```

It's mentioned [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php#datetime.formats.relative) in the manual.

Comment: Manual link has been [moved to here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php#datetime.formats.relative)

Answer (score 5):

**Manually creating a DateTime object with micro seconds:**

```
$d = new DateTime("15-07-2014 18:30:00.111111");
```

**Getting a DateTime object of the current time with microseconds:**

```
$d = date_format(new DateTime(),'d-m-Y H:i:s').substr((string)microtime(), 1, 8);
```

**Difference between two DateTime objects in microseconds (e.g. returns: 2.218939)**

```
//Returns the difference, in seconds, between two datetime objects including
//the microseconds:

function mdiff($date1, $date2){
    $date1sec = strtotime($date1->format('d-m-Y H:i:s.u'));
    $date2sec = strtotime($date2->format('d-m-Y H:i:s.u'));
    //Absolute val of Date 1 in seconds from  (EPOCH Time) - Date 2 in seconds from (EPOCH Time)
    $secdiff = abs($date1sec-$date2sec);
    //Creates variables for the microseconds of date1 and date2
    $micro1 = $date1->format("u");
    $micro2 = $date2->format("u");

    if (($date1sec<$date2sec && $micro1>$micro2)||($date1sec>$date2sec && $micro1<$micro2)){
        $microdiff = abs(1000000 - abs($micro1-$micro2));
        $secdiff = $secdiff - 1;
    } else {
        $microdiff = abs($micro1 - $micro2);
    }

    //Creates the variable that will hold the seconds (?):
    $difference = $secdiff.".".$microdiff;
    return $difference;
}
```

Essentially it finds the difference for the DateTime Objects using strtotime and then adding the extra microseconds on.

Do you need me to create add and sub?

Comment: You have wrong results if the difference between microseconds is greater then a second, other then that, as PHP does not support this, you're on the right track

Comment: Could you explain with an example? I thought it was impossible for the difference in microseconds to be greater than a second?

Comment: var_dump(mdiff(new DateTime('2010-01-01 00:00:01.800000+01'), new DateTime('2010-01-01 00:00:00.700000+01')));
var_dump(mdiff(new DateTime('2010-01-01 00:00:01.800000+01'), new DateTime('2010-01-01 00:00:00.900000+01')));
Both are returning the same "1.100000", shouldn't the second return 0.90000 ? Or I am to tired and in need or some caffeine :)

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar problem and ended up having to wrap the whole thing

https://gist.github.com/chandeeland/9817516

Answer (score 0):

For the people only in need to zero-out microseconds (I had to because of database layer) here's the snippet I ended up using:

```php
$format = "Y-m-d H:i:s e";
$now = (new \DateTime())->format($format);
$dateTime = \DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $now);
```

Note that using `$format = 'c'`, ISO 8601, will not work, as explained here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/10478469/8119317).

Comment: How does this answer the question? I think this achieves a DateTime object representing `now` but with microseconds zeroed. That's not what the question is about.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I was too deep lost in my own problem. Corrected the answer to mention that the solution is only for a special subcase.

Comment: I figured as much. There's a shorter way to do what you want (although if you run it on PHP < 7.1 it will throw an error): `$d->modify("-{$d->format('u')} usec");`

Answer (score 0):

##### PHP 7.1+

**Unambiguous approach** to set microseconds if you don't like natural string solutions:

```php
$dt = new DateTime();
$dt->setTime( $dt->format('H'), $dt->format('i'), $dt->format('s'), 999 );
// -------------------hour-------------minutes-----------seconds----^^^ microseconds
```

- Microsecond addition:

  - 1 second = 1,000,000 microseconds, and since [**`DateTime::setTime`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settime.php) accepts large integer values, you can simply add microseconds to the current value:
  - `$dt->setTime( ..., ..., ..., intval( $dt->format('u') ) + 123 )`
  - Adding 1000000 microseconds to e.g. 2 seconds will yield 3 seconds
- Microsecond subtraction:

  - Use the same approach as above to subtract:
  - `$dt->setTime( ..., ..., ..., intval( $dt->format('u') ) - 123 )`
  - Negative microsecond values are also accepted (value of -1 will turn e.g. 2 seconds to 1.999999)

Seems tedious? Just make a wrapper function to simplify the process :)