# PHP Unknown DateTime Format

Tags: php, datetime

I have the DateTime format: `2016-04-06T15:17:42.97074Z` that I obtained from v5 on the twitch api.

I need to turn this into the unix timestamp for comparison using PHP.

This is currently how I'm attempting the conversion into a DateTime object: `$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat(DateTime::ISO8601, $json["created_at"]);`, I have also tried using `DateTime::W3C` but to no avail.

`$json["created_at"]` definitely contains the time to convert as `echo $json["created_at"]` returns the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

createFromFormat rejects the fractional seconds when asked to parse ISO8601, but you can simply construct a DateTime using that string successfully, e.g.

```
$str='2016-04-06T15:17:42.97074Z';
//this will work... 
$dt1=new \DateTime($str);
//but this won't...
$dt2=\DateTime::createFromFormat(\DateTime::ATOM, $str);

var_dump($dt1);
var_dump($dt2);
```

This will output the following in [php 5.6.0 - 5.6.30, hhvm-3.15.4 - 3.17.1, 7.0.0 - 7.1.1](https://3v4l.org/qN9e6#v560)

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2016-04-06 15:17:42.970740"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(2)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(1) "Z"
}
bool(false)
```

See also [PHP DateTime::createFromFormat doesn't parse ISO 8601 date time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411340/php-datetimecreatefromformat-doesnt-parse-iso-8601-date-time)